# Why can I not attach ng-click to my element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

The `ng-click` event is not firing on my element. I have tried the in-line controller script given below. I am unable to hit my alert. Is there any integration problems I should be wary of? What could be the issue here?

```
 <a class="button black"><div class="light" ng-click="AddCrims()"></div>Add Crims</a>
```

---

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.AddCrims = function () {
        alert('hi');
     }
});
```

Appreciated if anyone helps me this. thanks.

Comment: What does your HTML / Angular look like? Your element with `ng-click`

Comment: How are you executing the function?

Comment: More information is needed. Can you show more of what you have?

Comment: What markup you are using on HTML?

Comment: @Adjit <a class="button black"><div class="light" ng-click="AddCrims()"></div>Add Crims</a>

Comment: @Thiyagarajan where are you declaring ng-app/controller in the UI?

Comment: @MarkC how are you executing the function means?  i have 3 files controller.js module.js and service.js

Comment: you have an empty `div` where you added the ng-click, is the css class `.light`  defined with `display: block` and does it have a width & height?

Comment: @Betty i have tried in both <a> tag and <div> tag.

Comment: @MarkC. I have added the ng-app in the <head ng-app="myApp"> in the body tag i have added <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

Comment: OK first you need to learn about HTML, and DOM structure... it would work if you put `ng-app` in the `html` tag because that one is surrounding the `body`-tag

Comment: @Betty now working fine, Change which i made in code below <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl"> instead of <head> Thanks for your help. thank you all for your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all essentials are correct e.g. `ng-app="myApp"` and in some way your controller is registered properly e.g. `ng-controller="MyCtrl"`, you need to add `ng-click` on your `<a>` - not `<div>` (which appears empty). Observe the following...

```
<a class="button black" ng-click="AddCrims()"><div class="light"></div>Add Crims</a>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/b9q648yu/) - working demo

---

- Note: if you intend to attach the event to the `<div>` - you'll need to ensure it's not an empty element some way or another e.g. define static height/width. As a further observation, it'd be worth noting that anchor tags should have a `href=""` attribute, even if empty, for accessibility purposes.

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vrn32vmx/) - example `<div ng-click="AddCrims()"></div>`

Comment: This is probably because the `<a>` captures the click event before the div has chance.

Comment: You can add it to the nested `<div>`, but as is - I have no idea what that element is. Without associated styles it's a 0x0 empty element as far as I am concerned. How can we click that?

Comment: @Chris most likely because of how the DOM layers are created, and that the element doesn't take up any space since there is no content in it or a fixed size that we know of. If you use `z-index` you may be able to pull the div in front of the anchor tags, thus executing the click no the `div`

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, either way your answer is correct I think

Comment: I agree with you on that. We'd need more info on what that `<div>` is all about. If styles properly - we can click it fine - [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vrn32vmx/)

Comment: i have tried without class in the div tag still it is not working.

Comment: It's not the class that's the issue, I took that out of my example prefix for brevity. Did you look at the example? Are you getting any JS errors? @Thiyagarajan

Comment: @scniro now it is working i can see the alert, The change i made below.<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl"> when i gave ng-app in  <head> it is was working.thanks for your support

Comment: @Thiyagarajan Cool - so while not the direct issue - hopefully you gained some valuable information here. I'll edit answer for succinctness. Please remember to accept if you found helpful?

Comment: @Scniro im loading calender control in  $(window).load(function () {
            alert('hi');

        }); if i am using this again function call is not working